# Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #192.168.1.3:8985_solr"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a JavaScript error.

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #192.168.1.3:8985_solr

```js
var replicasNodeName = "192.168.1.209:8983_solr";
$('"#' + replicasNodeName + '"').append('<a href="#"><span class="badge">5</span></a>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body" id="192.168.1.209:8983_solr"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate way is, to use native `document.getElementById()` method, then you won't need to escape meta-characters

```js
var replicasNodeName = "192.168.1.209:8983_solr";
$(document.getElementById(replicasNodeName)).append('<a href="#"><span class="badge">5</span></a>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body" id="192.168.1.209:8983_solr"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `.` and `:` characters as they have special meanings in a selector. To do that prefix them with `\\`. You also don't need the extra quotes within the string. Try this:

```js
var replicasNodeName = "192\\.168\\.1\\.209\\:8983_solr";
$('#' + replicasNodeName).append('<a href="#"><span class="badge">5</span></a>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body" id="192.168.1.209:8983_solr"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Damn ! you are fast Rory

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without any escaping would be the following:

See [jQuery Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp) for reference

```js
var replicasNodeName = "192.168.1.209:8983_solr";
$("*[id='"+ replicasNodeName + "'").append('<a href="#"><span class="badge">5</span></a>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body" id="192.168.1.209:8983_solr"> </div>
</div>
```